# Null String returned when reading from a socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to connect to a server ussing tcp/ip.

I'm able to connect to server but I get response as null.

**CODE**

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class Client {
        private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "192.168.64.79";
        private static final int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 6669;

        public void connect() {
            BufferedReader in;
            try {
                // Socket skt = new Socket("50.128.128.254", 6669);//ip,port
                Socket clientSocket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, TCP_SERVER_PORT);// ip,port

                System.out.println(" client Socket created ..Enter input : ");
    //          BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                String ToServer = "123";//inFromUser.readLine();
                outToServer.println(ToServer);

                 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));


                System.out.print("Received string: \n");

        //          while (!in.ready()) {
        //          }

// in is never ready
                    System.out.println(in.readLine()); // NULL returned

        //          System.out.print("'\n");
                    in.close();
                    System.out.print("connection closed");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
```

I have referred to [Getting Null String when reading from a socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553571/getting-null-string-when-reading-from-a-socket)

**EDIT**
Sometimes I get null response and some time I get connection reset error(for same inputs aswell)

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Tcp.Client.connect(Client.java:33)
    at Pms.main(Pms.java:8)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure server sends response? Meaning, are you sure that only your client doesn't get response?

Comment: No i'm not sure. I'm new to tcp/ip how can I verify that the server is not sending response . I'm currently not getting any exceptions

Comment: @RachitaNanda: can you provide the code of your server?

Comment: What do you expect to get when reading this line? If server won't write anything - there is nothing to read. Did you write your server? Put code of server if possible. Client looks ok.

Comment: Give your Server Code

Comment: I don't have the server code. I'm trying to communicate to a 3rd party server using simple commands, but I'm not getting any response or error message from server

Comment: `readLine()` returns null at end of stream. See the Javadoc. That means the peer closed the connection. Not sure why you find this inexplicable.

Comment: If you can't provide the server's code, you should post its documentation instead, otherwise noone here can judge whether you send correct commands.